# Django URL matching any 140 characters

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to map a view to any URL of the form home/text where text is any 140 characters (including spaces). Is there a simple way to do this? I tried:

```
url(r'^home/(?P<text>[\w]+)$',....),
```

but that did not allow spaces nor did it enforce any limit on length.

Any advice would be appreciated, as I couldn't find anything similar in the documentation and am new to Django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where text is any 140 characters (including spaces)

### Match words and spaces

You can add `{140}` to specify the length, and add `\s` to match spaces, to your URL regex:

```
url(r'^home/(?P<text>[\w\s]{140})$',....),
```

Here's how you can test it out, I've reduced it to 10 length to make it easy:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = r'^home/(?P<text>[\w\s]{10})$'
>>> re.search(regex, "home/1234567890").group(1)
'1234567890'
>>> re.search(regex, "home/12345 7890").group(1)
'12345 7890'
>>> re.search(regex, "home/ abcd fghi").group(1)
' sbcd fghi'
```

and if you exceed the length, e.g.

```
>>> re.search(regex, "home/ abcd fghizzz")
# Doesn't match, returns None
```

and if you go below the length, e.g.

```
>>> re.search(regex, "home/ abc")
# Doesn't match, returns None
```

### Match "anything" (not practical for a URL, because of e.g. `?` and `#`)

If you want to match pretty much anything:

```
>>> regex = r'^home/(?P<text>(.){10})$'
>>> re.search(regex, "home/1@#$%^& &*").group(1)
'1@#$%^& &*'
>>> re.search(regex, "home/1@bcd^& &*").group(1)
'1@bcd^& &*'
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. And then is there something I need to do besides \w in the brackets to allow for spaces?

Comment: This is not valid as \w won't match spaces or special characters
  
  [\w ] will match any words + spaces

Comment: I also need to accept special characters so I tried: url(r'^home/(?P<text>[.]{140})$',...) but this did not work, am I missing something?

Comment: `(.)` not `[.]`, added a section for what you tried in the answer

Comment: Thanks again, it now matches pretty much everything but if I input a string like "2??#" the text parameter only captures "2". Is there something I can to make it capture any character?

Comment: it seems to catch them for me, `regex = r'^home/(?P<text>(.){10})$'`, and `re.search(regex, 'home/2??#aaaaaa').group(1)` returns `'2??#aaaaaa'`

Comment: I think it is because characters like ? and # are reserved in urls from what I read. Not sure if there is a seperate way to handle them and still have them show up in the text parameter in my view

Comment: Ah yes I forgot this is a about URL hehe, but yeah I don't think it's going to be possible, you'll have to pass it as a string parameter to a GET, like `/home?text=...` and escape it properly, or another way